# How do you get audio into an iPhone app?

Tags: ios4

How do you display audio files like an imagepicker? I'm using the MPMediaplayer class but I can't get it to work. My requirement is to click on a tableviewcell, and have audio files appear like an imagepicker.

Comment: Please work on forming a coherent question. A simple spell checker will go a long way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simple get the path of all audio files. and parse the name only from the path. store all the names in array and display in UITableView. just read about how to use nsfilemanager.

Comment: how to get all files from device

Comment: how to use MPMediaPlayerController? plz help me

Comment: Rahul plz help me, hoe to give the path of my audiofiles.i m trying like this audioString = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"/Users/gvrao/Desktop/audio" ofType:@".mp3"]; Bt i didn't get

Comment: @Raju you need to add audio files to your application bundle. then use this method like this audioString = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"<Name_Of_Your_Audio_File>" ofType:@"Type"];  make sure to not use . when providing type.